# Error compiling GCC Ubuntu : undefined reference to

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, makefile, autoconf

I am trying to run a C project "https://github.com/karimaechihabi/lernaean-hydra/tree/91b480fb633ab4730a2cf1f5573d20d55b39b71e/hydra1/code/ucr-suite", following the same steps to auto generate configuration and makefile as in the read me :

```
>./autogen.sh \
>./configure \
>make
```

But when i run make file, i got this error of undefined reference :

```
>usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: src/bin_serial-serial_scan.o: in function `main': 
/home/zeraph/lernaean-hydra/hydra1/code/ucr-suite/src/serial_scan.c:143: undefined reference to `init_serial_stats'\
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/zeraph/lernaean-hydra/hydra1/code/ucr-suite/src/serial_scan.c:147: undefined reference to `serial_scan'\
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status\
make[1]: *** [Makefile:486: bin/serial] Error 1\
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/zeraph/lernaean-hydra/hydra1/code/ucr-suite'\
make: *** [Makefile:335: all] Error 2
```

***Any Help Please ?***

Ps : While runing the Configuration command to generate makefile, i also got this warning :

```
>/usr/share/automake-1.16/am/library.am: warning: 'lib/libserial.a': linking libraries using a non-POSIX \
/usr/share/automake-1.16/am/library.am: archiver requires 'AM_PROG_AR' in 'configure.ac'
```

Comment: Maybe the project has bugs? You're going to need to dig into the code some more and find out. If you can't get it to work, open an issue if you can and that's appropriate.

Comment: It seems to have problems with make dependencies, trying to build bin/serial before lib/libserial.a has been built. You can do `make lib/libserial.a` first, followed by `make` to build bin/serial, but that produces errors due to multiply defined global variables.

Answer (score 1):

The problems was with make dependencies(trying to build bin/serial before lib/libserial.a has been built);
Solution : first  do make lib/libserial.a first, followed by make to build bin/serial.

Comment: That's worth a nod for sticking with the problem and finding a solution. (you should probably open a ticket on github as well)